# Swing interface not updating componets when an event is fired from a trhread in another object

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, interface

I looked everywhere in the questions previously asked, and although some users had similar problems, none of the solutions worked for me.

My problem is that I have a Swing interface (main app) which provides a graphical way of working with sockets. The program allows the user to open/close sockets in client or server mode for UDP or TCP protocols. The Class that manages the TCP server connections, provides an interface for firing events (client connected, client disconnected, new message, etc). The main app implements that interface, and upgrade the Swing interface accordingly.

The mainapp goes something like this:

```
    public class mainapp implements TCPServerListener{

   private tcpServer TCPServer;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mainapp window = new mainapp()
                window.frmUdptcpPruebas.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void startTCPServer(){


            TCPServer= new tcpServer(new mainapp(), "");
            TCPServer.setListeningIP(this.textFieldIpLocal.getText()  );
            TCPServer.startTcpServer();


}


/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public pruebas() {
    initialize();

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    .
    .The swing interface has many more components, but Im just showing the
    .connect button to make the code more readable
    .
    btnConectar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            boton_conectar_presionado();
                startTCPServer();    
        }
    });
    .
    .
    .
    .       
}


@Override
public void onMessageReceived_TCPserver(byte[] b, String id,
            Socket remote) {


    }

@Override
    public void onClientConnected(final String id) {
    System.out.println("id");
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            comboBoxClients.addItem(id);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClientDisconnected(final String id) {



}

@Override
public void errorDetectedTCPserver(String errmsg) {


}
    }
```

So, every time a new client connects, the code within the onClientConnected method is executed. I know the code is indeed executed, because it prints the id of the clients, but the combobox is never NEVER upgraded (doesn’t matter if I’m changing the interface inside the EDT thread or not). I also checked the combobox.itemcount before and after the insert, and it is inserting the item, is just not upgrading the interface.

I've also tried many of the soluctions suggested here like using refresh, validate, revalidate and a long etc.

So, what is going on? Is it because the event is fired from a thread in another object??

Comment: You're probably not updating the combo box that is actually displayed on the screen. But with the partial code you posted, it's hard to spot the error.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be creating two instances of `mainapp`, one in the `main` method and another in `startTCPServer`.

Presumably it's the instance that created in the `main` method that's being displayed, while it's the instance that's created in `startTCPServer` that receives the callback when a client socket is connected.

In the method, `startTCPServer`, the line:

```
TCPServer= new tcpServer(new mainapp(), "");
```

Should read:

```
TCPServer= new tcpServer(this, "");
```

Comment: not read  trail EventDispatchThread in Oracle tutorial Concurency in Swing, btw SwingWorker is one of ways how to do it, a few times in SSCCE or MCVE or MCTRE form here, but I'd be preffer Runnable#Thread with invokeLater()